# How to make a list with scrollbar in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying make a list of 16 student and add scrollbar in the window

Problem : I can just see 14 students in the list

where is 15 and 16 ?

[1-10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UVx4.png)     [5-14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRkIK.png)

here's my python script :

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk


    root = Tk()
    y=800
    x=1180
    
    xy=str(x-85)+"x"+str(y-200)
    root.geometry(xy)
    
    
    main_frame = Frame(root,width=x,height=y-200)
    main_frame.place(x=0,y=0)
    
    my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, width=x, height=y-200)
    my_canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
    
    my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    my_scrollbar.place(x=1080,y=0,height=y-200)
    
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
    def _on_mouse_wheel(event):
        my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int((event.delta / 120)), "units")
    my_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mouse_wheel)
    
    second_frame = Frame(my_canvas,width=x,height=y-200)
    second_frame.place(x=0,y=0)
    
    my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
    try:root.iconbitmap("image.ico")
    except:pass
    
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 1',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=0)
    second_frame.configure(height=53)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 2',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=60)
    second_frame.configure(height=106)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 3',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=120)
    second_frame.configure(height=159)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 4',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=180)
    second_frame.configure(height=212)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 5',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=240)
    second_frame.configure(height=265)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 6',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=300)
    second_frame.configure(height=318)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 7',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=360)
    second_frame.configure(height=371)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 8',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=420)
    second_frame.configure(height=424)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 9',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=480)
    second_frame.configure(height=477)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 10',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=540)
    second_frame.configure(height=530)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 11',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=600)
    second_frame.configure(height=583)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 12',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=660)
    second_frame.configure(height=636)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 13',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=720)
    second_frame.configure(height=689)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 14',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=780)
    second_frame.configure(height=742)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 15',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=840)
    second_frame.configure(height=795)
    
    Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 16',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y=900)
    second_frame.configure(height=848)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

I tried change geometry and change (y) coordinates bur it doesn't work
please help me if you can

and thank you

Comment: Why don't you use `pack()` on those checkboxes? Then you don't need to adjust the height of the frame manually.

Answer (score 0):

They just don't fit into your frame - `second_frame.configure(height=848)`, but the placement coordinates `Checkbutton(second_frame, text='student 16',font=('Arial 0',20)).place(x=900,y =900)`. I increased the frame `second_frame = Frame(my_canvas,width=x,height=y+200)` and placed the checkbuttons in a loop, collecting them into a dictionary.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


number_students = 16
check_buttons = {}

def _on_mouse_wheel(event):
    my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int((event.delta / 120)), "units")


root = Tk()
y=800
x=1180

xy=str(x-85)+"x"+str(y-200)
root.geometry(xy)


main_frame = Frame(root,width=x,height=y-200)
main_frame.place(x=0,y=0)

my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, width=x, height=y-200)
my_canvas.place(x=0,y=0)

my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.place(x=1080,y=0,height=y-200)

my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

my_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mouse_wheel)

second_frame = Frame(my_canvas,width=x,height=y+200)
second_frame.place(x=0,y=0)

my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
try:root.iconbitmap("image.ico")
except:pass

for i in range(number_students):
    check_button = Checkbutton(second_frame, text=f'student {i+1}',font=('Arial 0',20))
    check_button.place(x = 900,y = 0 + i*60)
    # We collect checkbuttons in a dictionary, so that later we can find out their status.
    check_buttons[f'student {i+1}'] = check_button

print(check_buttons)
root.mainloop()

---------------------------
{'student 1': <tkinter.Checkbutton object .!frame.!canvas.!frame.!checkbutton>,
 'student 2': <tkinter.Checkbutton object .!frame.!canvas.!frame.!checkbutton2>,
........................................
```